# Visual Studio Code debugger reports "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE node.js" after script is completed

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-scripts, vscode-debugger

This is my very simple Node.js program configuration for VSCode:

**main.js**

```
const msg = "Hello World!";
console.log(msg);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --inspect-brk=9229 main.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Debug",
    "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "run-script",
        "start"
    ],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "port": 9229
}
```

Every time I run the 'main.js' script via 'Debug' launcher configuration at the very end when the script is already completed I'm getting this particular error in the TERMINAL window:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! debug1@1.0.0 start: `node --inspect-brk=9229 main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

**Except for these messages, everything works fine:** the script runs, breakpoints are triggered.

When I run it without VSCode debugger or with Chrome debugger these error messages don't appear.

What could be wrong with VSCode debugger or with my simple JS-script, configuration or what else it could be?

Comment: any more info or is there an issue on https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues?